# Order multiple curves on secondary axis

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to order my curves on the secondary y-axis, but i cannot figure out how to - anybody an idea?

i.e.

- first the blue curve starting at 0.01 on the second axis,
- then the orange curve starting at 0.1 on the secondary axis
- and so on ....
  Thanks

[image: How to order these curves on the secondary axis?]

[image: like this]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


def calc_curve(x, y):
    n = x / y
    z = np.abs(n * x - y) * (1 - (x / y) * np.exp(-x / y)) + \
                 np.abs(x - y) * (x / y) * np.exp(-x / y)

    return z

x_val = np.linspace(0.004, 0.4, 100)

# plot
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()
ax2 = ax1.twinx()

z_val = np.zeros_like(x_val)

for ts in [0.01, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3]:
    for c, tr in enumerate(x_val):
        z_val[c] = calc_curve(ts, x_val[c])

    ax1.plot(x_val, z_val, label="parameter: {0}".format(ts))

ax1.set_xlim(np.min(x_val), np.max(x_val))
#ax2.set_xlim(np.min(0.01), np.max(0.3))
ax1.legend()
plt.grid(True, which='both')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Honestly, I didn't catch what do you need. Do you want to start secondary axes from zero? Or whan?

Comment: I also don’t understand what you’re trying to achieve. Can you draw it by hand to illustrate?

Comment: think of it as the spacing between the curves. currently all curves intersect at a point (roughly 0.05) on the right axis; I want the first curve to start at 0.01, the second at 0.1, the thrid at 0.2 and the last at 0.4; 

or described from another perspective: I have a function f(x,y) = z; 
z is on the left axis,
x on the "x axis",
y on the right axis

Answer (score 1):

Based on the provided code, this is another answer:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


def calc_curve(x, y):
    n = x / y
    z = np.abs(n * x - y) * (1 - (x / y) * np.exp(-x / y)) + \
                 np.abs(x - y) * (x / y) * np.exp(-x / y)
    return z

x_val = np.linspace(0.004, 0.4, 100)

# plot
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()
ax2 = ax1.twinx()

z_val = np.zeros_like(x_val)

for ts in [0.01, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3]:
    for c, tr in enumerate(x_val):
        z_val[c] = calc_curve(ts, x_val[c])

    adjusted_z_val = z_val - z_val[-1] + ts
    ax2.plot(x_val, adjusted_z_val, label="parameter: {0}".format(ts))

ax2.set_ylim(-1, 2)
ax1.set_ylim(-1, 2)
ax2.legend()
plt.grid(True, which='both')
plt.show()
```

output is

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have to adjust your data to have the desired intercept on the right hand side. That is, you have to add a constant to your data series such that the last value equals the value you want to have. I give a a small example how to achieve this easily:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# generate two random time series
x = np.arange(1, 100)
y1 = (1 + np.random.rand() / 10)/x + np.random.rand()
y2 = (1 + np.random.rand() / 10)/x + np.random.rand()

# adjust data according to desired y intercepts
y1 = y1 - y1[-1] + 0.1 # 0.1 is the intercept you want
y2 = y2 - y2[-1] + 0.2 # 0.2 is the intercept you want

ax2 = plt.gca().twinx()
ax2.plot(x, y1)
ax2.plot(x, y2)
```

Output is as expected, line `y1` has its right-axis-intercept at 0.1 and `y2` at 0.2.

[image]
Also, please provide easy to copy examples so others can dive into your problem directly

Comment: thanks for your quick answer - even this really is the worse case i expected -
i attached the code as recommended ! :)